# PHP - why doesn't count() work like strlen() on a string?

Tags: php

A string is an array of characters, correct?  If so, then why does `count()` not produce the same result as `strlen()` on a string?

Comment: PHP doesn't always make sense like you want it to ;-)

Comment: @Matt Ellen it's the same for any lang, why not learn why there are different functions for different tasks?

Comment: @Raoul: what's the same? That different types have different functions applicable to them? Sure, but in some languages lists/arrays of characters and lists/arrays of anything else can be treated the same.

Comment: @Matt Ellen for clarification, no language makes sense if people jump to conclusions regarding syntax/features.

Comment: @Matt Ellen exactly, I was agreeing with you.

Comment: @Raoul: will delete my comment then :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A string is an array of characters in C, C++ and Java. In PHP, it is not. 
Remember that PHP is a very loose language, you can probobly get a character from a PHP string with the `[]`-selector, but it still dosn't make it an array.

Comment: I hate it when languages do that.  When I see array notation, I automatically think I'm working with an actual array.  It doesn't help that the PHP manual does not explicitly say "Strings ARE NOT arrays, despite having an indexer."

Comment: There are very few languages where a string is the same as an array. Maybe in C, but any higher level programming language will have a special structure for strings. Likewise, in C++, std::string can be accessed like an array, yet `sizeof(std::string)` won't give you the lenght. Just use the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 27):

Unless it is an object, [`count`](http://php.net/count) casts its argument to an array, and

```
  count((array) "example")
= count(array("example"))
= 1
```

Comment: This answer is much better than the accepted "not an array" answer, and is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

`count()` counts the number of entries in an `Array`.

```
$test = array(1,2,3);
echo count($test);
```

Output: 3

Why would you want to use `count()` on  a `string` when `strlen()` can do that? Are you not sure if your input is a `string` or an `array`? Then use `is_array()` to check that.

Comment: Yes, I know.  And if a string is an array of characters, then count() should return the number of characters in that string.

Comment: You could call a string an array of characters in English maybe, but in PHP it's not an array of characters, it's a string.

Comment: Kokos, the question is more about why strings aren't treated the same as normal arrays when they could be, in PHP. Haskell, for example, treats strings as a list of characters, so you can use all of Haskell's list functions on strings.

Comment: a string is not an array of characters, it can be converted to an array natively, but count() accept only as argument an array and strlen() a string

Comment: I was thrown off by the fact that strings have an indexer, and that the manual didn't explicitly say that despite the indexer, a string is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly a string is being handled internally by a specific programming language, must not necessarily mean you can handle it equally to therefore "related" data types. What you describe may be possible in plain C. However PHP is not C and so is not following the same characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

Strings are just a series of charactes, and `count` only counts number of elements in an array.

using $string[$index]; its just a shortcut kinda of thing to help you find Nth character,

you could use `count(explode('',$string));` which presumably is what `strlen` does

**so  lesson for today is**

count == array length

strlen == string length

Answer (score 0):

count gets the number of elements in an array, srtlen gets the length of a string. This is in the docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php

Comment: Yes, I know.  I was asking WHY that is the case.

Comment: @kevinmajor1 again, this is covered in the docs, if you read them.

Comment: I have read the docs.  They just weren't as clear on the matter as I had hoped.  See my comments above for why I immediately thought that strings were, indeed, character arrays.

Answer (score 0):

count is more preferabaly user for array value count
strlen its count only the no of char in str.....